# How to force a cold start in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm initializing a global variable from a file before the request code:

```
global_variable = open('file.txt').read()

def function(request):
    pass
```

When I update this file I would like to force a cold start so that the new file is loaded. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't all global variables' initialization code execute via cold start invocation? For your solution, you can use lazy loading (example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/functions/tips/main.py) or as suggested in the answer: periodically check the file state.

Comment: How does lazy loading solve my problem? And how would you implement periodically checking the file state?

Comment: Consider this example (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables) in Python, store file size initially, then you can use datetime module for sending lazy_load requests with evaluation function being size difference of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Developers aren't given any direct control over when cold starts happen.  From your question, it sounds like you might misunderstand how Cloud Functions works.

Each deployed function will have 0 or more server instances allocated to it so that it can handle incoming traffic.  Traffic is split among those running instances.  Every time a new server instance is allocated to handle increased load, that is going to incur a cold start *of that one new instance*.  That cold start doesn't affect other instances that might already be running.  Given that there are any number of server instances that come and go over time, there is no "global state" for a given function.  Functions should be designed to be stateless.

That said, you can make an instance "go away" by throwing an exception in the code it's running.  So, you could issue a request that forces the function to crash.  But you can't control which server instance a request will be routed to.  So, you could try to kill all of your running instances by delivering multiple requests (one for each server instance that you think might be running at the moment), but you are just not going to have a straightforward, reliable way to do this.

If you need to have your server instances reload something into memory, they will have to periodically execute some code that checks to see if something is updated.  That is the only reliable method.

Comment: But then the only way of forcing a cold start in every instance is redeploying the function? In AWS Lambda one can force a cold start of the functions by updating an environment variable for example, I couldn't see that behaviour in Cloud function docs though. Also regarding periodically run some code to check for file changes how would you implement that?

Comment: Sure, you can redeploy.  That will go through the process of migrating running code from old instances to new instances.  It is not instantaneous - the service will not stop handlling requests during the deployment, so you might have a mix of old and new instances serving traffic for a short while.

Comment: I guess I could have a flag variable that indicates when there is a file change and in each request check the flag variable and update the global variable if there is a change. Is this when you meant by periodically checking if it is updated or something else?

Comment: If this is a file that you deployed with the function and read locally from the running instance, then it's actually never going to change until you redeploy.  Deployments are all-or-nothing.  There are no partial deployments.  If this a file that you get from some remote location, then you'll have to fetch it again periodically.

Comment: @DougStevenson is this crashing trick a reliable method to cause gen1 function (or gen2 for that matter which I presume will stop other concurrent API calls) to re-deploy with newest code? In my architecture I'm able to retry calls, but I must ensure old code is not used (so I could check current newest version with Memorystore, then crash if given instance is too old).